# Do HTML frames/iframes have a cross-domain accessible unique id?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am currently hitting an issue where it would be helpful to have a unique ID for multiple frames on different domains, where the unique ID is publicly accessible to other frames that have a reference to that frame (e.g., the parent, a child iframe).  Clearly, each browser knows that each frame is unique and manages that information somewhere.

This issue comes up due to the HTML postMessage protocol.  If you start to stack iframes or have duplicate iframes (e.g., same URL, but two separate instances as iframes), it can get quite difficult to tell the difference between a message from frame A versus frame B.  For example, consider the following situation:

- Parent Frame: www.myparent.com/Parent.html

  - Child Frame 1: www.mychild.com/Child.html
  - Child Frame 2: www.mychild.com/Child.html
  - Child Frame 3: www.mychild.com/Child.html

Assume we send a message from the Child Frame 1 that we want to reach all other child frames.  After it has gone through the postMessage process, how do we even know that it came from Child Frame 1?  The URL for each is identical, so that is no help.  There are a few solutions (e.g., having each child send an initial message to register a unique sender id that they'll attach to each of their following messages, having the parent give each frame a URL parameter that can be used to distinguish between them).  However, the simplest solution would be if there was some property like frame.uuid (similar to frame.name), which both the child and the parent frame are aware of.

While it is clearly possible to emulate this functionality using HTML, I am building a library intended to make this process as easy as humanly possible, so if I can readily automate inferring these links (and surviving when two iframes have the same name), that would be important. It also needs to work for cross-domain purposes, so simply setting random DOM properties isn't an option.  More generally, I would be very interested in seeing a list of which frame properties are accessible for cross-domain purposes, in case it is possible to easily overload one to carry this uuid information.

Comment: To be absolutely clear on this, it doesn't matter what the ID is for each frame, so long as it has a low probability of collisions (e.g., essentially unique), the current frame can access it, it can be accessed by any other cross-domain frame with a reference to the current frame, and it works on any major browser.

Comment: As an update, all I have been able to find is window.name as a cross-domain accessible property to do this. However, it's a tremendous hack and has potential issues with race conditions, since you need to set the window.name on each page and hope the other page doesn't call it before it is set (or, god-forbid, change it).  Very odd that the standard doesn't involve some UUID for each frame that can be accessed by adjacent frames. Still hoping that I am missing something here.